# PIL crop image give incorrect height result

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('0009_jpg.jpg')

width, height = img.size #height is 720 and width is 480

if height > width:
    rm_height = abs(height - width) # rm_height = 240
    x_offset = 0
    y_offset = rm_height/2 # y_offset = 120
    tall = height-rm_height # tall = 480
    img_crop = img.crop((x_offset, y_offset, width, tall))

img_crop.save('crop_jpg.jpg')
```

output image is 480x360 resulution not 480x480

but when i change this line to

```
tall = height-rm_height/2 # tall = 600
```

output image is square 480x480

it's not make sense. what i do wrong. thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK after i search for more. Now i get it from this [post](http://labb.in/s/ZCwU)

Chris Clarke's ([edited](http://labb.in/s/ZCqu) by San4ez) answer:

```
import Image
im = Image.open(<your image>)
width, height = im.size   # Get dimensions

left = (width - new_width)/2
top = (height - new_height)/2
right = (width + new_width)/2
bottom = (height + new_height)/2

im.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
```

it's not tall. it is bottom

Comment: What does this say??

Comment: from Chris Clarke , it's say im.crop((left, top, right, bottom))